# Android - Get latest value from array and show in TextView

Tags: android, arrays, json

I'm stuck on getting latest value from the array coming from Ubidots in the form of JSON. I want to get the latest value from array and show it on TextView. here is my code of JSON. I'm using List here because i also populating the entire JSON into graphs. Now the problem is getting only 1 latest value from entire results

```
public class UbidotsClient {
private UbiListener listener;

public UbiListener getListener() {
    return listener;
}

public void setListener(UbiListener listener) {
    this.listener = listener;
}

public void handleUbidots(String Datasource ,String varId, String apiKey, final UbiListener listener) {

    final List<Value> results = new ArrayList<>();

    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
    Request req = new Request.Builder().addHeader("X-Auth-Token", apiKey)
            .url("http://things.ubidots.com/api/v1.6/devices/" + Datasource + "/" + varId + "/values/?page_size=100")
            .build();

    client.newCall(req).enqueue(new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Request request, IOException e) {
            Log.d("Chart", "Network error");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Response response) throws IOException {
            String body = response.body().string();
            Log.d("Chart", body);

            try {
                JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(body);
                JSONArray jRes = jObj.getJSONArray("results");
                for (int i=0; i < jRes.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject obj = jRes.getJSONObject(i);
                    Value val = new Value();
                    val.timestamp = obj.getLong("timestamp");
                    val.value  = (float) obj.getDouble("value");
                    results.add(val);
                }

                listener.onDataReady(results);

            }
            catch(JSONException jse) {
                jse.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    });

}


public static class Value {
    public float value;
   public long timestamp;

}

public interface  UbiListener {
    public void onDataReady( List<Value> result);
} }
```

This is the class where i'm getting the JSON response. Now where i want to show the latest value in text view is: The code where i'm trying to get the 1st value from array is in the onDataready() function. Please check my code and help me.

```
 public void callAsynchronousTaskHeart() {
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    doAsynchronousTask = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            (new UbidotsClient()).handleUbidots(Datasource, heartVarId, API_KEY, new UbidotsClient.UbiListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataReady(List<UbidotsClient.Value> result) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < result.size(); i++) {
                        float obj = result.get(i).value;
                        heartdata = Math.round(obj);
                    }
                }
            });
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    heart_rate.setText(String.valueOf(heartdata));
                }
            });
        }
    };
    timer.schedule(doAsynchronousTask, 0, 5000);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

i don't know i could understand what you want correctly or not but i am going to answer as i understood.

you can set the value to TextView directly from `onResponse` method by doing these steps.

1- create interface ... assume it's name is **textCallback**

```
interface TextCallback{
   void setTextViewValue(String value);
}
```

2- implement your interface to your activity and set the string value to your TextView.

3- pass this interface from your activity "using `this`" to **UbidotsClient Class** and create a member variable inside UbidotsClient class and set the incoming interface object to it.

4- in `onResponse` method set this line inside the loop.

```
if(i == jRes.length() -1)
    textCallback.setTextViewValue([SET THE VALUE YOU WANT]).
```

Answer (score 0):

if you only want last value then no need of looping .

```
JsonObject lastObject= jsonArray.getJsonObject(jsonArray.length-1);Value val = new Value();
val.timestamp = lastObject.getLong("timestamp");                          
val.value  = (float) lastObject.getDouble("value");
```

Comment: I'm looping because the i'm calling the same class from another fragment where i'm using charts, so to populate charts with data i'm looping to get all values and show up in charts.

Comment: the problem is how i can get the latest value from the array so that i can also show the latest value in textview too

Comment: you can filter list on the basisof the time stamp and get latest data. if you need latest data . you can use timestamp to get the list of latest data. of specific time like today